# i want to display record of day 1 day 2 and day 3 sales record

Tags: php, mysql

i tried many format on how to get the daily sales report but still now working

```
<?php 
    $sql="SELECT * from purchase where date > DATE_SUB(now() interval 1 day) order by purchaseid desc";
                                
    $query=$conn->query($sql);
    while($row=$query->fetch_array()){
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo date('M d, Y h:i A', strtotime($row['date_purchase'])) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['customer']; ?></td>
        <td class="text-right">&#8369; <?php echo number_format($row['total'], 2); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['modeOfPayment']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#details<?php echo $row['purchaseid']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> View</a>
        <?php include('sales_modal.php'); ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: What is your current return, does your query return someting, dump the `$query` variable  first and see if you have a return, if not, maybe your query is wrong. Always build failsaves to see what goes wrong. Not working is very broad, where is the issue exactly.

Comment: @David the error says 

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') order by purchaseid desc' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ordersimple\salesPerMonthReport.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ordersimple\salesPerMonthReport.php(25): mysqli->query('SELECT * from p...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ordersimple\monthlySalesReport.php(24): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\ordersimple\salesPerMonthReport.php on line 25

Comment: @David im sorry but i really dont understand the problem, i am new to php and mysql and i am just gooogleing things

Comment: @Dorvalla i want to display the sales grouped by day but still not working, it still display the sales by month

i changed the select data to $sql="SELECT * from purchase where DATE_SUB(now(), interval 1 day) order by purchaseid DESC";

Answer (score 0):

firstly there's a syntax error in the `DATE_SUB` function - you're missing a comma.  DATE_SUB requires two parameters.

Secondly, you'll want to `GROUP BY` to group the days.

If your data type is set to `DATE` then it will simply be:

```
SELECT *
FROM purchase 
WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

If your data type is `DATETIME` then just wrap the group by with the `DATE` function

```
SELECT *
FROM purchase 
WHERE `date` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
ORDER BY `date` DESC
```

P.S. the backticks either side of `date` are used, since date is a mysql keyword, so it simply escapes the keyword.  Try not to use "date" as a column name.  "updated_at" is likely a better name.